# Add product name to description tab

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I've tried adding:

```
<div class="product-name">
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getName(),'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

to description.phml but receive an error.

Do I have to make a new block for  product name and then add that via local.xml?

Comment: what is the error? update the question with that particular error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $_pname= $this->getProduct()->getName(); ?>

    <div class="product-name">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pname, 'name') ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works great thanks! I'm also trying to add a dropdown attribute using <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('producttype') ?> but get Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object

Comment: $productType = $_product->getTypeID();   From this you can get product type

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
<div class="product-name">
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $this->getProduct()->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

in this d`description.phtml $_priduct object is not exits`you got the error